# Excel - Using VLOOKUP to create a summary table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a little help with some Excel.

```
Employee  Locations     Hours   OT
Mr.One    Station 1     40      6
Mrs.Seven Station 2     30      6
Mr.Two    Station 3     30      4
Mr.Three  Station 4     40      4
Mrs.Eight Station 1     32      6
Mr.Four   Station 2     32      7
Mrs.Nine  Station 3     40      6
Mr.Five   Station 4     40      7
Mr.Six    Station 1     25      2
Mrs.Ten   Station 2     40      3
Mr.Eleven Station 3     60      1
```

I have spreadsheet with two worksheets. One is the data sheet (shown above), and the other sheet is a summary that has the `Locations` column as data validation list.  I want to use the data validation list to pull all the people and info from a specific location.  I tried using `VLOOKUP()` but I only know how to use it to pull one person at a time, not a group of records specific to a location.

Comment: take a look at [this page](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/10/25/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later, you can use the following solution (the `IFERROR` function is the limiting factor).  In the sample summary table shown in the screen capture below, I used this formula, filled down several rows, to return the Employees who matched the location chosen from the drop-down in B2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$1:$A$12,SMALL(IF(Data!$B$1:$B$12=Summary!$B$1,ROW(Data!$A$1:$A$12),2000000),ROW()-3)),"")
```

This formula must be entered as an array formula.  Do so by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In the hours column, this array formula was filled down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$C$1:$C$12,SMALL(IF(Data!$B$1:$B$12=Summary!$B$1,ROW(Data!$C$1:$C$12),2000000),ROW()-3)),"")
```

[image]

One thing to note about the formulas is the last argument in the `SMALL` function `ROW()-3`. This returns `1` for the first record in Row 4.  If your summary table starts at a different row, you will need to adjust this argument so that it returns `1` for the first row of your table.  For example, if your table starts in Row 2, you will need to change the argument to `ROW()-1`.